# indexOf() creating "cannot read property" error inside of *ngIf statement in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that's called in different areas of my site which has more components nested inside of it that I want to display depending on the route.  I came up with this solution.

```
import { Component }                        from '@angular/core';

var routeLocation = window.location.pathname;

@Component({
    selector: 'asset-packs',
    template: `<h1>Asset Packs</h1>
               <asset-expand *ngIf="routeLocation.indexOf('expand') > 0"></asset-expand>
               <asset-newbus *ngIf="routeLocation.indexOf('rebrand') > 0"></asset-newbus>
          `
})

export class PointAssetsComponent {

}
```

my intention was to use

> var routeLocation = window.location.pathname;

to pull the url from the browser and save it into a variable which I could then call in the *ngIf statement as

> *ngIf="routeLocation.indexOf('expand') > 0"

As you can see from the quoted out variables I've tried a few different ways of accessing the URL as well as swapping the exact text I want to look for for a variable with the text stored in it.  Either which way I'm getting the undefined error.

So far I haven't been able to find any examples of

> .indexOf()

specifically being used in ngular 2, but from what I've seen about it I'm using the right syntax with it.  I was originally trying to use

> .contains()

and got the same error.  When I delete the ngIf statements both components show up without a problem.  It's just when I add them in that this problem starts occurring.

I've come across a few other articles on this issue where they said it was a bug caused by AngularFire and FireBird modules in Node.  I checked and neither of those are in my app.

The only thing I figure is it has to be something with the syntax or I'm not importing something that makes the

> window.location.etc

parts work.  Does anybody know what's causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in your ts file:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
export class PointAssetsComponent {

public navExpand:boolean = false;
public navRebrand:boolean = false;
constructor(private router: Router) {

    }
if (this.router.url.substring(0,7) === '/expand'){
this.navExpand = true;
} else if (this.router.url.substring(0,8) === '/rebrand'){
this.navRebrand = true;
}
```

**HTML**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'asset-packs',
    template: `<h1>Asset Packs</h1>
               <asset-expand *ngIf="navExpand"></asset-expand>
               <asset-newbus *ngIf="navRebrand"></asset-newbus>
          `
})
```

Comment: unfortunately I got errors when I tried this.  But it led me on the right path to a solution that works.  Only difference is I called it in the ngOnInit using window.location.pathname as a variable to run the if condition you came up with.  I put it in the Oninit because once I got the Constructor picking up on it properly it wouldn't update the path when I went to another section.